# Does cross product depend on the orthogonality of the basis vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, inner-products, cross-product, infinitesimals

When I learn cross product, I find myself always using orthogonal basis vectors (e.g. **$\hat{i}$**, **$\hat{j}$** and **$\hat{k}$**). But I am wondering does cross product depend on the orthogonality of the basis vectors? i.e. can I calculate the cross product of two vectors which are written in a set of non-orthogonal basis vectors? Why or why not?

Also, what if the basis vectors are changing (e.g. in cylindrical polar coordinates)? Why is cross product still defined in such a set of basis vectors?

How about for dot products? Does the dot product depend on the orthogonality or invariation of the basis vectors? Why or why not?

Comment: In [spherical polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4730303/949989) we have $$
\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
$$

Comment: and in [cylindrical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704593/949989) we have $$\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=-\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\,$$ which should take us quite far.